# How do I connect and get info for specific Availability zone?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to get data for certain objects that are in a specific Availability Zone (`ec2.ap-southeast-2b.amazonaws.com`) but fail to set:

```
ec2Config.ServiceURL = `http://ec2.ap-southeast-2b.amazonaws.com`
```

And get a `NameResolutionException`!

How can I get the data (I try: ProductionClient.DescribeVolumes()) for this specific AZ??

Comment: The api endpoints are the same for a whole region. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

AWS service endpoints are specific to a whole **Region** rather than just an Availability Zone.

So, the URL should be: `http://ec2.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` (without the 'b')

For a list of Endpoints, see: [AWS Regions and Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ec2_region)

Comment: I AM targeting the URL you mentioned! BUT I DO NOT get certain volumes in the result!! Volumes which are in that AZ are NOT returned! WHY?

Comment: Are you saying that the volumes appearing in the AWS Management Console, but not in the API call? Have you tried the call by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws ec2 describe-volumes`?